# Can we use regex within sed

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I have a sample file with many sections. There can be multiple new lines within a section. So, we can encounter multiple new lines (\n) within a section.

```
Section1

Section2
(
    (a)   (b)
    (c)   (d)
    (e)   (f)
))

Section 3
```

I want to replace all the contents of Section 2 with some other content. So, one thing I am aware is that section closes with consecutive ) brace. Is there a way I can do it via a `sed` using regex. I want to do it via only shell script only.

I know I can give

`sed/findpattern/replacementtext/g`

How do I add a `regex` here to populate `findpattern`. Can I give a full fledged regex here?

Expected Output

```
 Section1

    Section2
    (
        (m)   (n)
        (o)   (p)
        (q)   (r)
    ))

    Section 3
```

Only Section 2 contents need to be found first and then it needs to be replaced with some content like above.

Comment: What is your expected output? Give a minimal, verifiable input and expected output.

Comment: I have updated the query.

Comment: Are you using `GNU sed`? check the output of `sed --version`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `c`(change) command:

```
sed '
/Section2/,/))/c \
    Section2 \
    ( \
        (m)   (n) \
        (o)   (p) \
        (q)   (r) \
    ))
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, here is an example I came up with that you can use to fit your needs:

```
echo 'foo (a) bar' | sed 's/\((\)\([a-zA-Z]*\)\()\)/\1something_else\3/'
```

Input:

```
foo (a) bar
```

Output:

```
foo (something_else) bar
```

\1 and \3 represent the group open and close parenthesis, while \2 group has the content that are in between those two parenthesis.

Comment: Can I have sed take input as some txt file and then read the contents of file and replace it.  echo someFile.text | sed expression

Comment: @Geek I used echo as an example but you can use a file directly with sed, e.g. sed 's/replace/with/' input.file

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to indent the section, you can simply insert four spaces (or a tab) at the start of each line:

```
sed '^/Section2/,/^))/s/^/    /;' file
```